# ALT world & Mega Pencil - what does my money get me?

Tags: pokemon-picross

I've been playing Pokemon Picross for a little while, and enjoying it, but I've started to hit the pay wall now. The game doesn't seem to be very good at explaining what some of the higher priced unlocks will actually get you, and I'd like to make an informed decision before spending any real life money!

ALT world is 800 picrites: 
I've done the ALT world tests, so know that it unlocks the slightly different types of puzzles, but how many puzzles do you get, and are there additional unlocks where you have to shell out more? (like the standard stages unlock)

Mega Pencil is 500 picrites:
Is this to play the one stage, or once I've purchased this can I play any of the Mega pencil stages. What is different about this puzzle?

The Nintendo e-store says that if I purchase 5000 picrites *you will  be able to obtain Picrites for free in this shop*, so about £28.78 of real life monies. Does this mean you get unlimited picrites once you hit this, or that they give you a one off bundle of *x* picrites?

Are there any other unlocks further in the game which require more picrites? (Other than the standard unlocking of the next world & unlocking Pokemon slots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**Alt World**](http://serebii.net/picross/altworld.shtml):

> **Alt World** is a repeat of all of the stages in the standard world, but with a twist. These puzzles are done a bit differently. All the puzzles in the standard world are duplicated so you can get Pokémon here if you haven't yet got them in the main world. Each stage also has its own set of challenges and Picrite rewards for completing them.
>   However, while the Pokémon in each area is the same between worlds, the placement and order of them varies.

Regarding [**Picrites**](http://serebii.net/picross/picrites.shtml):

> You have to spend 300 Picrites to get to the Alt World and 500 Picrites to get the Mega Pencil to complete Mega Evolved Pokémon stages.

So you have to buy the *Mega Pencil* just once.

And about **micro-transactions**:

> You can only purchase up to 5,000 Picrites in the lifetime of the game. Once you have done this, however, you'll be able to get free Picrites. You'll then be given them in batches of 1,000 until you hit 8,000 in your pack preventing you from running out of them at any time in the future game play.

Source [Serebii](http://serebii.net/picross/).

Comment: Are both of these things one off unlocks? I thought I'd have to pay each time I wanted access to an alt world.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Yep, they're just one time unlocks. Atl World is a unique entity, you don't have to pay for each Alt World area. It won't be feasible.